# Python - Pulling data from API (Not limiting to the default 100 rows of data that get returned)

Tags: python, api

I am trying to pull data of a API and it looks like it only returns back the first 100 rows. I am trying to see how can we alter the value from the default 100 to say 1000 or so.

```
url = "https://api.keka.com/v1/employees"

payload={}
headers = {
'Authorization': 'Authorization',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

This is the documentation on the API but I am not sure how to pass in the pagesize argument as mentioned there. Any help here would be appreciated.

```
https://developers.keka.com/?shell#keka-api-employees
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:
[image]

You can add those parameters to `payload`:

```
payload={"pageindex":2, "pagesize":100}
headers = {
'Authorization': 'Authorization',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

I haven't interacted with the api, but that is basically it

Comment: thanks for getting back. I tried your suggestion but even that returns back the first 100 rows

Comment: @KevinNash, are you sure? Did you try changing the pageindex? Is it still only the first 100?

Comment: yes, I tried different page index values and also page size but it returned back the same 100 rows

Comment: Well, I don't have authorization, so I am not able to replicate your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
      url2 = "enter your url"
         YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN = "enter your access token"
               headers = {
                      'content-type': 'application/json',
                        'authorization': 'Bearer %s' % YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
}

       response2 = requests.request("GET", url2, headers=headers, data=payload)


js2 = json.loads(response2.text)

allResults = list()
counter = 0

while(js2['paging']['next']['link']!=""):
  allResults.extend(js2['results'])
  url2 = js2['paging']['next']['link']
  print(url2)
  response = requests.request("GET", url2, headers=headers, data=payload)
  js2 = json.loads(response2.text)
  counter = counter + 1

  out_file = open("companiesNEW.json", "w")

  json.dump(allResults, out_file, indent = 6)

  out_file.close()
```

#this will make all your data in one sigle json file.